# pytest coverage never runs function body

Tags: pytest, coverage.py, pytest-cov

I am using vscode with pytest and pytest-cov in order to generate a coverage report for my tests. However, no matter what I do the report always indicates that no code was run, event though I know the test functions call the code in question.

My project structure, simplified for clarity, is

```
Root
 ├── src
 |    └──my_package
 |         ├──__init__.py
 |         └──my_module.py
 ├── tests
 |    └──my_package_tests
 |         ├──__init__.py
 |         └──my_module_test.py
 └── pytest.ini
```

`pytest.ini` contains

```
[pytest]
addopts = --cov=my_package --cov-report=html:./reports/coverage_report
```

The tests import and call functions from `my_package`

When I run the tests, and look at the generated report, I can see that lines in `my_package` are being marked as having run when the module is imported, but no code in the function bodies are being marked as executed. The test are passing so the code is being executed.

I'm at a loss on this one. I've tried doing this via command line only, uninstalling pytest-cov and trying manually, but nothing has worked.